# Finding Maximum value from a Varchar Field

Tags: php, database-design, mysql

I have a database field know as SCORES which has Scores
the value may be like the following

123

14

56*

342

423*

I am storing that in a Varchar Field in the database.

Suppose If I convert that to a integer a datatype, then I can write 
max(SCORES) and get the Maximum score or Highest Scores.
But Integer doesnot allow special character like *.

(Here * represent some clause for that scores)

To accomadate that I have made that to the varchar.

What will be best way to get the Highest score very easily with minimum programming method.

So that If I execute a query I should be get the answer as

423*

Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this situation is to change you table structure to make

- `SCORES` of `int` data type.
- Add a new field in the table called
  `clause`
- If most of your `SCORES` are without a
  `clause`, you must normalize the table
  to move the `clause` field to a
  different table.

Comment: If I do this, there will be lot of data entry work, as I have nearly 60000 rows which I need to get the data.

Comment: should have thought about that before you HACKED up a solution

Comment: Now trying to get the best way to come out of it

Answer (score 1):

You should change table schema ...

```
SELECT scores
FROM tablename
ORDER BY replace(scores, '*', '') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @harigm - The above query will return `423*` exactly. You should change your column to ensure optimization is taking care

Comment: Means column type needs to be changed? if this really works for 1 million records, that will be awesome, please let me clearly Will do and test it

Comment: @harigm - You can duplicate an extra column without the asterisk, and add an index on that column, sort always using that column, while you still can display using result (with asterisk) using the original column

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should be generic for getting maximum score, today you have only '*' is attached with score but in future may be you use some others character or may be you use some combination of character so you should take care of that scenario.

so i thing it will be better if you create a user define function which takes varchar as a input and return number from input string like if you pass '1234*' then function will return 1234 and if you pass 1234** it will return 1234.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseNumeric
(
  @string VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
  SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z]%', @string)
  WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @string = STUFF(@string, @IncorrectCharLoc, 1, '')
    SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
  END
  SET @string = @string
  RETURN @string
END
GO
```

then use:

```
select max(cast(dbo.ParseNumeric(score) as int)) from tableName
```

Comment: While something like that woudl work, it would perform badly. The only real solution is to fix the poor table design.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(scores AS SIGNED))
  FROM tablename
```

But this query will be quite slow, since it cannot be optimized using indexes.

Comment: This works, but give you a warning 'Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '11*'

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(REPLACE(FIELD,'*',''),signed)) FROM TABLE
```

It:

- Replace the * from your varchar
- Covnert the result into integer (signed)
- Select the MAX value

**EDIT 1:**

I have been tring the SQL with some data, i have a table with one field (varchar, no key), I've inserted 62962 values (one each 1000 have a '*', the results as follow :)

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(REPLACE(FIELD,'*',''),signed)) FROM TABLE
```

Took 0.0666sec.

```
SELECT scores FROM tablename ORDER BY replace(scores, '*', '') DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Took 0.089sec to execute and got the wrong value:

HTH :)

Comment: How about executing the query with 1million records, will that be a expensive one

Answer (score 0):

You could move the asterisk to a new field (depends if you need it or not). After that you can change the datatype.

```
UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    score = REPLACE(score, '*', ''),
    specialCharField = IF(CONTAINS(score, '*'), '*', '');
```